# How to get JSON response from $http.put() AngularJS to Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

Code below makes a `$http.put()` request to the server to update an `item`. The request successfully updates the db, but does not return an object to `.success()`..
It seems strange because `$http.post` and `$http.delete()` actions **are** returning JSON objects.

Is this normal with `$http.put()`?

app.js

```
i.edit = function(id, item) {
    return $http.put('/items/' + id + '.json', {item: item}).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

items_controller.rb

```
def update
    item = Item.find(params[:id])
    item.update_attributes(item_params)
    respond_with item
end
```

Comment: Could it be that item.update_attributes() returns a status code and not the whole object?

Comment: It is returning a status code. But should it not return the object from "respond_with item" ?

Comment: Oh, yeah you're right. Does the callback even get called? Try replacing success with then